# Changes in TokenizerFactory class in SOLR/Lucene 4.5.1

Tags: solr, lucene

Now TokenizerFactory doesn't have setLuceneMatchVersion and init method and also expects Map from its constructor. I have been creating TokenizerFactory instance using newInstance method of ResourceLoader and then pass Map parameter thru init method like the following:

```
tokenizerFactory = (TokenizerFactory) loader.newInstance(className, TokenizerFactory.class);
tokenizerFactory.init(params);
```

Now that init is gone, I am getting compilation error. How can I pass a parameter to the constructor in this syntax? Is there any other way?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use the static method `TokenizerFactory.forName(String name, Map<String,String> args)` for this? If not I'd post it as answer

Comment: I ended up using it eventually :) I should have read the documentation more carefully. If you can add your comment as an answer below, I will select it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the static method `TokenizerFactory.forName(String name, Map<String,String> args)`.

```java
Map<String,String> args = new HashMap<>();
TokenizerFactory.forName("some.tokenizer.name", Map<String,String> args);
```